# Problems with references to objects being dropped in javascript

Tags: javascript

```js
var a = [],b = [],c = [{}];
b = a;
a = c;
a.push("asd");
console.log("a : " ,a);
console.log("b : " ,b );
```

In this code, Why is b different from a?

I want b to refer to a.

However, if a refers to c, b no longer refers to a.

Comment: You assigned reference of `a` to `b` then you changed the reference `a` was holding. Hence they are different

Answer (score 0):

`b` refers to what was *originally* assigned to `a`, but since you assigned `a` to `c` later in your code it is no longer true that `a === b`.

Your problem might be clearer in this example:

```js
var a = ['Originally a']
var b = ['Originally b']
var c = ['Originally c', {}]
b = a
a = c
a.push('asd')

console.log('a = ', a)
console.log('b = ', b)
console.log('c = ', c)
```